# Passing UTF-8 chars to jmeter using CLI from TFS

Tags: jmeter, command-line-interface

CLI mode is sending "-Jregid=ТА96090838" this UTF-8 character correctly but in JMeter request it turns into "Ã�Â¢Ã�ï¿½96090838" this.

My content encoding is set as UTF-8, before thread I used `prev.setDataEncoding("UTF-8")` in JSR223, also used `chcp 65001` this code page and checked Language for non-Unicode programs setting in windows setting.

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you need to explicitly set the `file.encoding` [Java System Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) to `UTF-8` via -D command line argument like:

```
jmeter -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Jregid=ТА96090838 .....
```

in order to make change permanent add `file.encoding=UTF-8` line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

More information:

- [Guide to Character Encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)